# Number theoretic statement which follows from ZF+AC, and whose negation follows from ZF+$\neg$AC

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let's denote by ZF the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms, and by AC the Axiom of Choice.
I am sorry that the question is not very well formulated, but still:

can there be a "number theoretic statement" (by which I understand a 1st order logic sentence in the language of sets which is true iff a certain "number theoretic" fact is true), such that it follows from ZF+AC, and whose negation follows from ZF+$\neg$AC?

Comment: The negation of axiom of choice, if you don't restrict yourself to number theoretic statement.

Comment: ["For even if AC is as a matter of fact false, it cannot lead to false elementary assertions about the integers, unless ZF already does."](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151905/328173)

Comment: ["There is a metatheorem that the Axiom of Choice is not necessary to prove any statements of Arithmetic, any proof of a statement about integers that uses AC can be constructively transformed into a proof which does not use that axiom."](https://mathoverflow.net/a/118976/91375)

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "sentence in the language of Peano Arithmetic" when you say "number theoretic statement"

Answer (score 2):

There are no first-order sentence like that.

If $\varphi$ is such sentence, then it holds in $V$ if and only if it holds in $L$, which satisfies choice. So if $\varphi$ follows from choice, it must holds in $L$ and thus in $V$, so it cannot be disproved by $\lnot\sf AC$. And similarly, if $V$ satisfies $\lnot\sf AC$, and $\varphi$ holds there, it must hold in $L$.

In fact, you can push $\varphi$ to a relatively simple second-order sentence, $\Sigma^1_2$ specifically, by [Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem).

Comment: I say we close it as duplicate of the first question I linked to.

Comment: What do you mean by V and L? (sorry, I have no formal education in set theory, and the informal one is quite limited).

Comment: $V$ is the usual letter denoting "the" set theoretic universe. $L$ is Gödel's constructible universe where the axiom of choice is provably true.

Comment: @KennyLau: For that to be "we" someone else had to vote as well... :P

Comment: Although Shoenfield absoluteness is about $\Sigma^1_2$ sentences, it actually lets you eliminate AC from proofs of $\Pi^1_4$ statements. If ZFC proves $(\forall x)(\exists y)\phi(x,y)$, where $x,y$ range over reals and $\phi$ is $\Pi^1_2$, then in just ZF you can argue as follows. Given any $x$, look in $L[x]$, which satisfies AC, and find some $y\in L[x]$ such that $L[x]$ satisfies $\phi(x,y)$. By Shoenfield absoluteness, $\phi(x,y)$ holds (in $V$).

Comment: @Andreas: That is pretty damn cool.

Comment: I think this argument for $\Pi^1_4$ is in a paper, "Eliminating the continuum hypothesis" by Richard Platek, which, despite the title, also has results about eliminating or reducing uses of AC.